Printing bash function body and including the comments in the body
I am using shdoc to generate markdown files for my bash functions; however, I would like also to append the associated bash function body as well as the comments in that body to the markdown file generated by shdoc. How can I print a bash function body while also including the comments in the function body?
As a simple example, consider that all my bash files are contained in a directory called src and all those files end in .sh. The function below in file src/foo.sh
# @description A function that does something
foo() {
  # oh wow, a comment
  echo "something cool"
}

Now, if I want to get the function body without comments I can do this easily with declare -f as shown below in a file called src/doc.sh:
# assuming you are in the `src` dir and both .sh files are executable
. foo.sh
foo_doc=$(declare -f foo)
echo "$foo_doc"

But the problem is foo_doc only has the function body, since echo "$foo_doc"
foo () 
{ 
    echo "something cool"
}

and no comments at all. So if I were to append this information to a markdown generated by shdoc, it is not an ideal documentation of the source code.
I think one approach would be to use sed to determine the lines corresponding to the function of interest (my bash functions are "delimited" by { and }, though per the comments I understand there are other ways to declare valid bash functions), then I could use sed to get only those lines as done here.

"of course, the bash function is delimited by { and }" -- that's not mandated by the language. For instance, you can write foo() (echo "this runs in a subshell") Shell Functions. But of course that's very unusual.

Ah, I didn't know that! For my purposes, all functions are delimited by { }, but it's good to know they can be delimited in other ways.

Note that the body isn't really "delimited" at all; the body of a function is any compound command, which includes not just {...} and (...) but if statements, loops, arithmetic statements, etc.

Since you have access to the files that contain the function definitions, you could do this with any POSIX awk:
awk '
    /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\(/ && ($1 !~ /^(if|elif|for|while|until)$/) {
        inFunc = 1
    }
    inFunc {
        print
        if ( /^[})]/ ) {
            inFunc = 0
        }
    }
' src/*.sh

It's not 100% robust but will probably be good enough for your functions if they look like the example you provided (i.e. start with alphanumeric_name ( at the start of a line and end with a } or ) at the start of a line) and you don't have any other code in your scripts that also looks like that but is not a function definition.
Add more keywords to the $1 !~ test if you like or you can make it more robust by adding a call to declare -F and then only accepting apparent function definitions matched by the above regexp if the string matches an actual function definition as reported by declare -F.
For example:
$ cat src/tst.sh
# The following is a function
# that does amazing things.
foo() {
  # oh wow, a comment
  echo "something cool"
}

# other code
if (( $# > 1 )); then
    echo "Eureka"
fi

# This function, however, is
# useless, can't believe we
# bothered to write it.
bar() {
  # this sucks
  # hope it doesn't get called
  echo "the sky is falling"
}


$ . src/tst.sh


$ declare -f foo bar
foo ()
{
    echo "something cool"
}
bar ()
{
    echo "the sky is falling"
}


$ declare -F foo bar
foo
bar


$ declare -F |
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        funcs[$3]
        next
    }
    /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\(/ && ($1 in funcs) {
        inFunc = 1
    }
    inFunc {
        print
        if ( /^[})]/ ) {
            inFunc = 0
        }
    }
' - FS='[[:space:](]+' src/*.sh
foo() {
  # oh wow, a comment
  echo "something cool"
}
bar() {
  # this sucks
  # hope it doesn't get called
  echo "the sky is falling"
}

and if you'd like to get any comments that end on the line immediately before each function too:
$ declare -F |
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        funcs[$3]
        next
    }
    /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\(/ && ($1 in funcs) {
        printf "%s", cmt
        inFunc = 1
    }
    { cmt = (/^#/ ? cmt $0 ORS : "") }
    inFunc {
        print
        if ( /^[})]/ ) {
            print ""
            inFunc = 0
        }
    }
' - FS='[[:space:](]+' src/*.sh
# The following is a function
# that does amazing things.
foo() {
  # oh wow, a comment
  echo "something cool"
}

# This function, however, is
# useless, can't believe we
# bothered to write it.
bar() {
  # this sucks
  # hope it doesn't get called
  echo "the sky is falling"
}

Note that that will only print the functions defined in your files and which are available in your environment, unlike the first script which will print all of the functions in your files.

It's a bit of a hack, but you can use colon comments:
foo() {
    : This is a comment
    echo foo this bar
}

Explanation: : in bash is a no-op command. You can pass it whatever arguments you want, and it ignores them. So this "comment" is actually technically a command which is part of the function body that does nothing. You have to be careful though, if your comments include special characters you'll have to quote them.

You do need to be very careful: this will delete the important file: : caution, do not `rm important-file` !

...accordingly, it's safer to explicitly pass : a lone single-quoted string -- : 'This is a comment' isn't parsing any of This is a comment for syntax.
